# Show User on Map if they are inside Radius

Tags: android, google-maps

When I tap on map then I am storing all my user's `LatLng` in `SharedPreference`. Now I am drawing a circle then If any user comes in this Circle then Marker should be visible. I am able to do all that but its showing only one user. But I have multiiple LatLng in my sharedpreference. How can I do thi? Please gide me. My code is here

```
 private void calculateUserLocation(MapAreaWrapper draggableCircle) {
    float[] distance = new float[10];

    Location.distanceBetween(map_flag.getPosition().latitude, map_flag.getPosition().longitude,
            draggableCircle.getCenter().latitude, draggableCircle.getCenter().longitude, distance);

    if (distance[0] > draggableCircle.getRadius()) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Outside", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        map_flag.setVisible(true);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inside", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: If its showing only one user could be because the other users have been overwritten. Are you using ArrayList to store the LatLngs? if not, i would suggest you do so. Then loop through each value and run it through your distanceBetween() method.

Answer (score 1):

```
 private Marker mMarker;

     private void calculateUserLocation(MapAreaWrapper draggableCircle) {
        float[] distance = new float[10];

        Location.distanceBetween(map_flag.getPosition().latitude, map_flag.getPosition().longitude,
                draggableCircle.getCenter().latitude, draggableCircle.getCenter().longitude, distance);

        if (distance[0] > draggableCircle.getRadius()) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Outside", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            map_flag.setVisible(true);
     if (map!=null){


//Simple Marker 
        Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(LatLng)
                .title("Hamburg"));

//marker With icon 
        Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(LatLng)
                .title("Kiel")
                .snippet("Kiel is cool")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
    }

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inside", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
```